# by checking all checkboxes via jquery = jquery ajax action of each checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

i have a jquery link which check/uncheck all checkboxes

```
$('#check_all_link').click(function(){
    $('.checker').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

when i check manually one checkbox i send it via jquery to a script:

```
$("input.checker").click(function() {

    var check_active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    var photo_id = $(this).attr('value');
    var photodb_id = 6;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "jobticket_ajax/cart.php",
        data: {photo_id: photo_id, check_active: check_active, 
        photodb_id: photodb_id},
        success: function(){

        }
    });
 return true;
 });
```

How can i send $.ajax via $('#check_all_link').click(function() too (what do manually if checked)?

Comment: add `$('.checker').click()` after the prop change to trigger a click event on them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I guess,

```js
$(".chk").change(function(){
    if ($('.chk:checked').length == $('.chk').length) {
       alert('Ajax call');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='check[]' /> Check 1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='check[]' /> Check 1</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='check[]' /> Check 1</label><label><input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='check[]' /> Check 1</label>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: i need the ajax action on every checkbox when check all checkboxes via link

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$('#check_all_link').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('.checker').each(function(i, chk){    
        $(chk).prop('checked', checked);
        $(chk).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the solution

```
$('input.active').trigger('click');
```